# What kinds of out-of-band failures am I forgetting to test?

Tags: testing, network-programming, distributed, distributed-computing, robustness

I came across an amazing presentation years ago (which of course I can't find) that listed a bunch of kinds of failures for remote services that people usually don't test for.

In addition to timeout, 4xx, 5xx, etc, it listed things like:

- connection closes after 10 bytes of data
- returns contents of www.google.com
- returns contents of /dev/random
- returns contents of /etc/passwd
- returns correctly-formatted unicode chinese text
- returns ansi color control characters
- returns an incorrect content-type, labeled correctly (You requested Content-Type: application/json, I send back Content-Type: application/jpeg)
- returns one byte of data every 29 seconds

**What are some types of "out-of-band failures" you've encountered that developers don't usually (but should) test for?**

*(extra bonus points if you can find the original presentation)*

Comment: "years ago" can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: also what was the context of the presentation, diagnostics or security?

Comment: Around 2014, and it was about testing distributed systems.

Comment: What is the difference between `contents of www.google.com`, `contents of /dev/random` and `contents of /etc/passwd`, from an application point of view? Wouldn't you normally just look for expected data, and fail in the same way each time because you can't find it in any of those 3 responses? For example, if your app tries to parse the response as JSON, those 3 test cases will result in the same exception?

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester The parser that's expecting HTML might die in a bad way when it gets binary data ie it failed the test. Or it might correctly handle bad input by providing a proper error message ie it passed the test.

Answer (score 2):

The ones you listed are great; I'd love to see the original presentation if you dig it up! A couple other favorites:

- A "valid" response with a [couple bits flipped](http://noahdavids.org/self_published/CRC_and_checksum.html)
- A "valid" response with extra data you weren't expecting (`{"result": 123, "extraStuff": {...}}`) to simulate upgrades to the remote side
- A syntactically-valid response that never ends (`{"results":["lol", "lol", "lol", ...`, or just a bunch of whitespace)

Answer (score 0):

Low-frequency failures. In other words, test that some response is correct not just once, but every time out of a thousand tries. You'll get random Internet breakage if you're going over a network, but you might expose some process is stochastic when you thought it was fixed.